# How to display selected value-from-dropdownlist-after form submit

Tags: c#

I have a dropdown list in my form . After submitting the form I don't get selected value from the dropdown list in UI. I only get first value . How to implement this . How to display dropdown selected value after form submit .

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ViewState or Sessions to save the variable and reuse it, It would look something like this:

```
private void Page_Load()
{
        //If page is not being loaded for first time then set the value another 
        //option would be to check if ViewState["dropdownvalue"] == null and if 
        //not then set the value
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {       
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = ViewState["dropdownvalue"]
    }
}
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{   
    ViewState["dropdownvalue"] = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;  
    // Do everything else
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I want to display dropdown selected value after form submit

Comment: So you want to keep the selected value after leaving the page?

Comment: In that case use Sessions, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5282677/how-to-use-session-variable-in-asp-using-c-sharp they are basically a way to transfer data between pages. ( I define my sessions in Global.asax but i'm not completely sure its necessary, just a practice of mine). Let me know if this is what you are looking for and i'll update my answer

Comment: after page load the dropdown selected value is gone . I want to show the selected dropdown value into dropdown UI like selected = selected

Comment: You need to save the value of the dropdownlist in a Session (now that I think about it a ViewState would work better) and when you reload the page set the Dropdownlist value to the session value